# MAUI Canceling ColorTo Animation hangs

Tags: animation, maui

I have got a BoxView in MAUI that's Color is animated  with the ColorAnimationExtensions.ColorTo method.
When I want to stop the animation via AbortAnimation("ColorTo"), sometimes the system just hangs.
I thought it might be a problem when I'm trying to stop inexisting animations, so I use

```
void CancelAnimation(BoxView box)
{
    if (box.AnimationIsRunning("ColorTo"))
        box.AbortAnimation("ColorTo");
}
```

Doesn't help. What am I overlooking?

I am starting the animation like this:

```
static async void BlinkSlowly(VisualElement element, Color c1)
{
    if (element is BoxView b)
            await b.ColorTo(c1);
}
```

Here is the stack of the hanging process

```
    System.Collections.Concurrent.dll!System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<System.Type, System.Func<Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope, object>>.TryGetValueInternal(System.Type key, int hashcode, out System.Func<Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope, object> value)  Unknown
    System.Collections.Concurrent.dll!System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<System.Type, System.Func<Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope, object>>.GetOrAdd(System.Type key, System.Func<System.Type, System.Func<Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope, object>> valueFactory)  Unknown
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(System.Type serviceType, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) Unknown
    Microsoft.Maui.dll!Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.WrappedServiceProvider.GetService(System.Type serviceType)    Unknown
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(System.IServiceProvider provider, System.Type serviceType)   Unknown
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService<Microsoft.Maui.Animations.IAnimationManager>(System.IServiceProvider provider)   Unknown
    Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll!Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ViewExtensions.GetAnimationManager(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.IAnimatable animatable)  Unknown
    Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll!Microsoft.Maui.Controls.AnimationExtensions.Animate<double>(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.IAnimatable self, string name, System.Func<double, double> transform, System.Action<double> callback, uint rate, uint length, Microsoft.Maui.Easing easing, System.Action<double, bool> finished, System.Func<bool> repeat, Microsoft.Maui.Animations.IAnimationManager animationManager)   Unknown
    Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll!Microsoft.Maui.Controls.AnimationExtensions.Animate(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.IAnimatable self, string name, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Animation animation, uint rate, uint length, Microsoft.Maui.Easing easing, System.Action<double, bool> finished, System.Func<bool> repeat)   Unknown
    Mmss.dll!ColorAnimationExtensions.ColorTo(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BoxView element, Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color color, uint rate, uint length, Microsoft.Maui.Easing easing, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) Line 102    C#
    Mmss.dll!MauiApp1.MainPage.BlinkSlowly(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement element, Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color c1, Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color c2, uint rate, uint millisecs) Line 39    C#
    [Resuming Async Method] 
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.__Canon>.ExecutionContextCallback(object s) Line 287   C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Line 183  C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.AsyncStateMachineBox<MauiApp1.MainPage.<BlinkSlowly>d__103>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread) Line 324    C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.__Canon>.MoveNext() Line 302   C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__12_0(System.Action innerContinuation, System.Threading.Tasks.Task innerTask) Line 302   C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ContinuationWrapper.Invoke() Line 149 C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation..cctor.AnonymousMethod__17_0(object state) Line 671 C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTask) Line 697  C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.Run(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool canInlineContinuationTask) Line 412    C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(object continuationObject) Line 3387    C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations() Line 3352  C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>.TrySetResult(bool result) Line 401 C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<bool>.SetResult(bool result) Line 198    C#
    Mmss.dll!ColorAnimationExtensions.ColorTo.AnonymousMethod__0(double d, bool b) Line 109 C#
    Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll!Microsoft.Maui.Controls.AnimationExtensions.AbortAnimation(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.AnimatableKey key)   Unknown
    Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll!Microsoft.Maui.Controls.AnimationExtensions.AbortAnimation.AnonymousMethod__0() Unknown
    Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll!Microsoft.Maui.Controls.AnimationExtensions.AbortAnimation(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.IAnimatable self, string handle) Unknown
```

Comment: Do you mean [BackgroundColorTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/extensions/color-animation-extensions#backgroundcolorto) for BoxView? Besides may I know what platform and .NET version you use?

Comment: No, I mean ColorTo.  It's from ColorAnimationExtensions.
This hang occurred very often on "Windows machine" Target .NET version 6.0.
System Info: VS Community 2022 
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.5.3+33516.290
Microsoft .NET Version 4.8.09037

Comment: Could you please show more code how you use your ColorAnimationExtensions? I think you may refer to this official docs : [Create a custom animation extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/animation/custom?view=net-maui-8.0#create-a-custom-animation-extension-method) and tried the code.

Comment: By the way, .net6 is out of support (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/maui). It's better use .NET7/8.